# Force browser to query server for file even if it's cached, and prevent use of bfcache

Tags: node.js, firefox, caching

Firefox on my PC ended up caching my Node.js server scripts extremely hard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ignored) after I started sending this header:

```
    resp.writeHead(code, {
      "Content-Type": mime.lookup(path),
      "Content-Length": stats.size,
      "Cache-Control": "public, max-age=3672000",
      // Write file last modified header
      "Last-Modified": stats.mtime.toUTCString()
    });
```

The problem is that the browser caches files in back-forward (`BFCache`) cache instead of HTTP cache and even after about a week (during which I debugged in Google Chrome instead) still remembers them and does not revalidate. I'd like to make browser remember the `Last-Modified` timestamp, always send request to server and **my server** will decide whether to send the file or `304 - Not modified` header.

Apparently this problem is somehow related to Require.js, the issue only affects javascript files loaded by that framework.